# C#: Why is drawing slow?

Tags: c#, drawing, gdi+

Im drawing a linear gradient manually by drawing lines with changing colors. However, this is very slow, and i seems to update, when i resize the window. How do i make it faster? The color scale is linear in this example, but later i wan't to make non-linear gradients.

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs paintEvnt)
        {
            SuspendLayout();

            // Get the graphics object
            Graphics gfx = paintEvnt.Graphics;
            // Create a new pen that we shall use for drawing the line

            // Loop and create a horizontal line 10 pixels below the last one
            for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++)
            {
                Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(i/2,0,0));
                gfx.DrawLine(myPen, 0, i, 132, i);
            }

            ResumeLayout();

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is that GDI+ is incredibly slow.**

You should use high level constructs with GDI+ which are relatively fast (relative to drawing lines like you do now). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush.aspx for more information about e.g. the `LinearGradientBrush`. There are much more of these brushes and pens which should help you increase your performance.

One more thing: the `Suspend/ResumeLayout` doesn't do anything in your example. These methods only apply when you are doing layout by e.g. adding `Control`s to the current form or changing properties on existing `Control`s like the `Dock` property or the `Height` and `Width`.

Comment: @Pieter - i've tried using the liniargradienbrush, but i doesn't allow me to do non-linear gradients, which is what, im trying to accomplish.

Comment: I understand. However, the approach you are taking, however understandable it is (been there, done that :) ), is painstakingly slow. That's GDI+ for you. If this is for a custom control, you can try setting `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true)` in the constructor. This does help.

Comment: @Pieter - Ok, this resulted in an improvement, but for now its still too slow. Is XNA the only alternative to GDI+?

Comment: @Bildsoe - I would very very seriously consider WPF. I've made the switch and am not looking back. WPF is DirectX based so these problems simply do not apply.

Comment: @Pieter - Looking forward, I can see the benefits from changing to WPF, but right now i'm developing plugins for a platform that doesn't support WPF.

Comment: @Bildsoe - I would be very surprised if that platform will support XNA.

Comment: @Pieter - It doesn't - i just found out. But creating a bitmap as suggested my someone, and setting it on the background works for now. Then i'm gonna start looking into WPF.

Comment: @Bildsoe - what platform are we talking about?

Comment: @Bildsoe - ok, but you are using WinForms in these plunging? We have successfully hosted XNA in WinForms controls.

Comment: @Peter - yes I use WinForms in these plugins. Ok, is there anywhere i can read about hosting XNA in WinForms controls?

Comment: @Bildsoe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150521/where-can-i-find-code-samples-for-xna-with-winforms

Comment: Thanks! sorry for the late answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to paint it once and only once, without resizing, I suggest you write this to a Bitmap object once, and then draw this bitmap to the background. Also, you can enable double buffering on the form. this should be a property called DoubleBuffering, or something similar. This should reduce the flashing you get when redrawing your form.

Answer (score 1):

You could pre-compute the color values so you won't have to do it on every redraw. Other than that, there's not much more you can do without resorting to more lowlevel APIs, like XNA.

**Update:** it is perfectly feasible to host XNA within WinForms controls. There's some nice links forward in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150521/where-can-i-find-code-samples-for-xna-with-winforms).

Comment: Yep storing array of Pen outside the method, creating it only once, should improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps specifying a [`ColorBlend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.colorblend.aspx) to use with the `LinearGradientBrush` suggested by Pieter will address your concerns about being able to paint non-linear gradients in the future?

You can create a `ColorBlend` object that specifies the colors of your choice and an arbitrary position for each. By setting the `InterpolationColors` property of the `LinearGradientBrush` to your `ColorBlend` object, you should be able to get any effect that you want.

MSDN gives the following sample:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //Draw ellipse using ColorBlend.
    Point startPoint2 = new Point(20, 110);
    Point endPoint2 = new Point(140, 110);
    Color[] myColors = {Color.Green, Color.Yellow, Color.Yellow, Color.Blue, Color.Red, Color.Red};
    float[] myPositions = {0.0f,.20f,.40f,.60f,.80f,1.0f};
    ColorBlend myBlend = new ColorBlend();
    myBlend.Colors = myColors;
    myBlend.Positions = myPositions;
    LinearGradientBrush lgBrush2 = new LinearGradientBrush(startPoint2, endPoint2, Color.Green, Color.Red);
    lgBrush2.InterpolationColors = myBlend;
    Rectangle ellipseRect2 = new Rectangle(20, 110, 120, 80);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(lgBrush2, ellipseRect2);
}
```

Comment: This is also a good solution for now - but as i wrote to Pieter, hopefully i'll be doing the transition to WPF soon.